# Is there a .net equivalent of apache commons.lang ReflectionToStringBuilder?

Tags: .net, tostring

This has to be some kind of FAQ. I want to log an object's full state to a log file (using log4net, but that should be irrelevant) and I'd rater not override `ToString` for each one of my classes. Is there anything ready made I should use? I'm thinking of something similar of java commons.lang `ReflectionToStringBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not trying a simple serialization when possible ? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815813

Comment: I don't think XML serialization fits here. Isn't it a bit too verbose?